# Control flow using try/except

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I'm a newbie when it comes to Python. I have some python code in an azure sql notebook which gets run by a scheduled job. The job notebook runs a couple of sql notebooks. If the 1st notebook errors I want an exception to be thrown so that the scheduled job shows as failed and I don't want the subsequent sql notebook to run to run. The python code is as follows

```
%python
try:
    dbutils.notebook.run("/01. SMETS1Mig/" + dbutils.widgets.get("env_parent_directory") + "/02 Processing Curated Staging/02 Build - Parameterised/STA_1A - CS note Issued", 6000, {
        "env_ingest_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_ingest_db")
      , "env_stg_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_stg_db")
      , "env_tech_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_tech_db")
      })
except :
    print ' Failure in STA_1S'
try:
    dbutils.notebook.run("/01. SMETS1Mig/" + dbutils.widgets.get("env_parent_directory") + "/02 Processing Curated Staging/02 Build - Parameterised/Output CS Notes", 6000, {
        "env_ingest_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_ingest_db")
      , "env_stg_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_stg_db")
      , "env_tech_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_tech_db")
      })
except :
    print ' Error in Output CS Notes'
```

Am I heading in the right direction?

What's the best way to achieve this?

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: Simply don't catch the exception. Just run the first command without the `try` ... `except`, and let the exception bubble up in the normal way.  If it is raised (i.e. thrown), then the second command (or anything after it) will not be run.  You would then only catch exceptions with the second command.

```
dbutils.notebook.run(...first invocation...)  # exceptions not caught - will bubble

try:
    dbutils.notebook.run(...second invocation...)
except Exception as exc:
    print(' Error in Output CS Notes: {}'.format(exc))
```

**Option 2**: If you want to do some kind of handling of your own, then do catch the exception, but re-`raise` it (or another exception) within the `except` block.

```
try:
    dbutils.notebook.run(...first invocation...)
except Exception as exc:
    print(' Failure in STA_1S: {}'.format(exc))
    raise exc
    # or for example:  raise RuntimeError

# ... then do as before with second invocation...
```

(You can also use `raise` without any arguments instead of `raise exc`, as it will default to re-raising the original exception.)

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses, I'll have a play and let you know how I get on

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag that shows whether the first notebook succeeded or not:

```
first_notebook_succeeded = False # assume failure
try:
    dbutils.notebook.run("/01. SMETS1Mig/" + dbutils.widgets.get("env_parent_directory") + "/02 Processing Curated Staging/02 Build - Parameterised/STA_1A - CS note Issued", 6000, {
        "env_ingest_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_ingest_db")
      , "env_stg_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_stg_db")
      , "env_tech_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_tech_db")
      })
except :
    print ' Failure in STA_1S'
else:
    first_notebook_succeeded = True

if first_notebook_succeeded: # only run if first notebook ran OK
    try:
        dbutils.notebook.run("/01. SMETS1Mig/" + dbutils.widgets.get("env_parent_directory") + "/02 Processing Curated Staging/02 Build - Parameterised/Output CS Notes", 6000, {
        "env_ingest_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_ingest_db")
      , "env_stg_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_stg_db")
      , "env_tech_db": dbutils.widgets.get("env_tech_db")
      })
    except :
        print ' Error in Output CS Notes'
```

You can, of course, also set `first_notebook_succeeded` initially to `True` and then set it to `False` if the first notebook gets an exception.

Comment: This would certainly work, but it is for a different use case, namely to continue execution while skipping the execution of the second command. Here, the question says "I want an exception to be thrown". And the easiest way to throw an exception is not to catch it in the first place!

Comment: @alaniwi But the OP's question's heading is **Control flow using try/except**. The OP then goes on to say, "I want an exception to be thrown so that the scheduled job shows as failed." But the OP does have a print statement in the exception handler to show that the scheduled job has failed as a result of that exception. So, it is not entirely clear that this is *not* what he means. And we don't whether there is other code beyond the two notebooks that need to get executed. Not catching the exception at all would prevent that code from being executed.

Comment: Okay, yes you're right - looked at that way, the question is perhaps a bit ambiguous. Ah well, he/she has various options now and can have a play...

Answer (score -1):

Sorry - I did not read the question carefully enough.

My original answer is not what you are looking for.

I wrote:

> Add a `return` statement:
>
> ```
> try: 
>     # ...
> except Exception as error:
>     print f'Failure in STA_1S ({error})'
>     return
> ```

But you not only want to leave the function, but actually end it's execution with an error code.

What you are looking for is [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

> Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the SystemExit
> exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try
> statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit
> attempt at an outer level.
>
> The optional argument arg can be an integer giving the exit status
> (defaulting to zero), or another type of object. If it is an integer,
> zero is considered “successful termination” and any nonzero value is
> considered “abnormal termination” by shells and the like. Most systems
> require it to be in the range 0–127, and produce undefined results
> otherwise. Some systems have a convention for assigning specific
> meanings to specific exit codes, but these are generally
> underdeveloped; Unix programs generally use 2 for command line syntax
> errors and 1 for all other kind of errors. If another type of object
> is passed, None is equivalent to passing zero, and any other object is
> printed to stderr and results in an exit code of 1. In particular,
> sys.exit("some error message") is a quick way to exit a program when
> an error occurs.

So, here is my revised answer:

```
import sys

try: 
    # ...
except Exception as error:
    sys.exit(f'Failure in STA_1S ({error})')
```

Comment: Is that it?? What does the return statement do